# Create a slider that control a variable that itself control multiple properties all with Python

Tags: python

I want to create a script that control camera focal length based on the distance of the camera to it's target.

I'm able to create an addon, using operators with custom buttons, but I've never done something that requires a value to update every time the user move an object (in this case the camera). How do you approach this?

Ultimately the user should be able to move the camera and move the target independently, and the camera focal length should adapt to this changes in distance live. I also want a slider that control focal length independently, to choose what my base focal length is.

I don't need help with the trigonometry and math aspect of this, I'd just like some directions regarding how to implement this in the UI. Does this have anything to do with custom properties?

Comment: Drivers would do most of this.

Comment: Yes? Do you know any good tutorial that shows how to work with drivers in Python please? I've only use drivers for basic stuff before. Also I'm making an addon so everything should be script.

Comment: I'm sure, you can find [all about drivers here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drivers) already. Just search for it or ask a new question and also *provide your code* -> probably faster getting a real solution anyway. Alternatively I'd suggest have a look into the new custom gizmos. *Text Editor > Templates > Gizmo...*. Note: This question is too broad and probably better suited for a forum like blenderartists.org